# How to define this $db to my functions?

Tags: php, class, hook

I have a problem here. I am currently making a hook, which runs a function inside a class, but it goes wrong..

It says that the variable 'db' is not defined.

Exactly error is:
`Notice: Undefined variable: db in /home/turborpg/public_html/script/lib/class.gamebase.php on line 72`

Here is the source of the hook I run:
http://pastebin.com/aKZZaafr

And here is the source for the class.gamebase.php:
http://pastebin.com/fGVnY9JD

Hope someone are willing to help me out here. I am new with hooks and classes, this is my first try to make a custom one.

Comment: Those pastebins expire in a month - please either use non-expiring or paste the code in here.

Comment: Try using `$this->db` instead

Comment: The pass by reference that you are doing is unnecessary (&$db) if you are using a fairly current version of PHP.  All objects are now passed by reference.

Comment: @kaiser Oh.. Well, I only know how to paste single line codes in here.. As I am new to the site, so how can I paste multi-lines codes here to?

Comment: FYI (FROM PHP.net - http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)- Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

Comment: @MarkoLivendo For multi-line code directly in your posts, just add 4 spaces (or a tab) in front of each line of your code.

Comment: @Asad When I do that, nothing really happens, no error comes up.. So I tried echo out the function, and then I got `Resource id #56` back.. What does that means?

Comment: @JoshuaKaiser So, should I just change it from `(&$db)` into `($db)`?

Comment: @MarkoLivendo That's right.  The & isn't needed, and is in fact, deprecated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `$db` as a variable in your method. You should use it as a property `$this->db`.

Comment: When I do that, nothing really happens, no error comes up.. So I tried echo out the function, and then I got `Resource id #56` back.. What does that means?

Comment: @MarkoLivendo `So I tried echo out the function` which function? You cannot access php functions as `$this->func_name` - this will access the `func_name` property.

Comment: I echo out this:  
      `$GamebaseObject = new Gamebase($db);
      echo $GamebaseObject->nameExist($db);`

Comment: 1: nameExists haven't got any parameters. 2: this means $db->execute returns a resource (this depends on what db-layer you use) 3: this has nothing to do with the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you apparently are not clear on how to use class variables. Inside several of your methods you reference $db:

```
return $db->execute('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `main_games` WHERE `url`=?', array($this->getSubdomain()));
```

This needs to be:

```
return $this->db->execute('.....');
```

Make sure that anyplace you are using the protected $db variable in your class, you reference it properly.

Comment: When I do that, nothing really happens, no error comes up.. So I tried echo out the function, and then I got `Resource id #56` back.. What does that means?